# Selfrelationship of account

Tags: trigger, relationships

How to define self relationship in salesforce
  explain how can i create self relationship in salesforce. I know salesforce doesn't provide out of the box this relationship.

My Scenario is i have a Company object. Every company should have a parent company which can be any other company. If parent is not defined then current company automatically become the parent of itself.

Can anyone explain how can i achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be able to create a lookup field on your Company object to another Company object which would allow you to create your hierarchy. You could then use a workflow rule to update this when the parent is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create self relationship to custom object directly to itself by using "Related To" labelled pick-list. It doesn't have its own name in it.

Closest you can do is create another custom object and add master detail from parent custom object to children and then again another relationship from children custom object to parent.

In case of lookup relationship you can add same custom object.